# C# WPF Binding a text file to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I bind a text file to a datagrid with C# WPF? The idea is to have a row in the text file to show as a row in datagrid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can bind text directly to a datagrid

What you can do however is bind an objet to a datagrid

create an objet representing your text file.

```
-- content --  
text1, param1, param2  
text2, param1, param2  

class OneLine{
  string text {get;set;}  
  string param { get;set; }
  ...
}
```

You can then bind those objects to the datagrid with a BindingList, which is mostly a List. The magic lies in the Properties of the object. The BindingList will try to get each property of the object and display them in the grid.

```
BindingList<OneLine> myList = new BindingList<OneLine>();
myList.Add(oneObject);

DataGrid myGrid = new DataGrid();
myGrid.DataSource = myList;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use the following approach

1. Create class that represent row in text file for example

   ```
   public class cls_syslog_record
   {
       public DateTime? f1 {get;set;}
       public string f2 {get;set;}                
       public string f3 {get;set;}
       public string f4 {get;set;}        
   }
   ```
2. Create IEnumerable that used as source for DataGrid

   ```
   public IEnumerable<cls_syslog_record> get_line_seq_text()
   {
       cls_mvs_syslog_parser parser = new cls_mvs_syslog_parser();
       foreach (string record_line in File.ReadLines(this.filename))
       {
           cls_syslog_record text_record = parser.parse_syslog_text(record_line);
           if (text_record == null)
           {
                continue;
           }
           yield return text_record;
        }
   }
   ```
3. set my IEnumerable object as source

   ```
   static private DataGrid make_text_viewer(string p_filename)
   {
       logger.Debug("start");
       DataGrid table_viewer;
       cls_file_line_seq fl_seq = new cls_file_line_seq(p_filename);
       table_viewer = new DataGrid();
       table_viewer.CanUserAddRows = false;
       table_viewer.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
       table_viewer.Columns.Add(create_column("Date Time", "timestamp"));
       table_viewer.Columns.Add(create_column("LPAR Name", "lpar_name"));
       table_viewer.Columns.Add(create_column("JOB ID", "job_id"));
       table_viewer.Columns.Add(create_column("Message", "message"));
       table_viewer.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.All;
       table_viewer.ItemsSource = fl_seq.get_line_seq_text();
       return table_viewer;
   }
   ```
4. Then setup binding

   ```
   static private DataGridColumn create_column(string header, string p_property_name)
   {
       DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
       column.Header = header;
       column.Binding = new Binding(p_property_name);            
       return column;
   }
   ```